# Save button is missing in binding navigator

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datasource, bindingnavigator

I just tried to add a new Binding Navigator for a certain grid view, and Save button is not showing up. Now if I try to delete grid view and re-add it, the Binding Navigator doesn't show up even if it should according to the docs.

Is there some rule when Save button will show up depends on grid view setup ? Also why  VS doesn't always add bind navigator automatically when we drag and drop data-source on the form?

The grid view I am talking about is not read-only, and it is set to an appropriate data-source so it shows the correct data. Bind navigator BindingSource is set to the same data source as grid view is.

If you need more info please let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Save button in `BindingNavigator` is not a built-in button and doesn't have a standard and built-in behavior. When you drop a data source from *Data Sources* window on your form, it adds the button for you and generates some code if possible. The button will not be added automatically when you drop `BindingNavigator` from tool-box.

You can simply add it yourself like any other `ToolStripBotton` items and add some code for its `Click` event handler.

If you are looking for the common look and feel of the save button, right click on your `BindingNavigator` and choose *Insert Standard Items* and from inserted items, just keep the inserted save button.

Comment: Yeah, I was looking for the standard items... Still, I don't know why VS sometimes include this by default and sometimes not. But I guess I will figure it out eventually.

Comment: When you drag a class/table from *Data Sources* window and drop it on a list control like a `ListBox` or a `DataGridView` it doesn't create a `BindingNavigator` for you. But if you drop it on an empty area of the form, it will add a `BindingNavigator` as well. Also about the *Save* button, when you drop a class, the `BindingNavigator` will contain a disabled save button, but about tables having `TableAdapter`, it will contain an enabled save button having some code generated for save.